# coldfusion/xml - accssing XmlText value in a single node using XPath

Tags: xml, xpath, coldfusion

I am parsing through a large xml document, and some of the values that I need are in the XmlText portion of node

Here is an example:

[image]

I can access the value using doing the following:

```
<cfset vinNode = xmlSearch(vehicleNode[1], "p:VehicleID")>
<cfset vin = vinNode[1].xmlText>
```

But I've know there is a better way using XPath, but I cannot seem to figure out the proper way to do it.

I've tried a number of different things, but nothing seems to work.

Any suggestions?

Comment: are you asking for a cleaner looking way or a way to chain it together into one statement? You should be able to use `<cfset vin = xmlSearch(vehicleNode[1], "p:VehicleID")[1].xmlText>` if you're on CF10. I know that won't work on CF8, not sure about 9 though.

Comment: I just have a bunch of these, and I am just trying to cut down on the amount of code.  works perfectly.